# How can I access to firebase storage within HTTP triggered firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have HTTP triggered firebase function that need to access the firebase storage, do some work on some file on it, and send back the result, but
when I run this code I get

```
    exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        const fileName = request.query.fileName; 
        const bucketName = request.query.bucketName; 
        const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName); 
        const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName); 

        bucket.file(fileName).download({
            destination: tempFilePath
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Downloaded file");

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("failed downloading file");
            console.log(error);
        });
        response.send("tried downloading file"); 
    });
```

It get to the catch part with the error

```
ApiError: vactive-backend@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to vactive-backend/my_script.py.
```

I checked that I made that bucket public, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Number 1 and 2 are separate questions, so please post them separately. For #1: the function ends when you send a response to the client. So just do the work, and only send the response when you're done.

Comment: Splitted the questions. Thanks for the answer, will do.